# Data back when default dialer app is launched - Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Does anyone know if the default dialer app in Android gives back any data which can be readed in onActivityResult() function? Something like this

```
//Button click:
startActivityforResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number)), 0);

//OnActivityResult
if(resultCode == CALL_NOT_ANSWERED)
   //do sth like try again
if(resultCode == VOICEMAIL_STARTED)
   //bad luck
if(resultCode == CALL_ANSWERED)
   //nice one
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the data returned, but if it suffices to see if the call was made or not, you could query the [CallLog.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) using the tel number that you have, and check the duration of last call.

Comment: Mark as answer or arrow up if it helped, tks :-)